# What do the dashed extended green lines on this PFD mean?

Tags: avionics, glass-cockpit

[image]

The most important source of information for the pilot is the PFD

Comment: This is not a Primary Flight Display. It's an MFD, EHSI or similar.

Comment: @pericynthion It's referred to as a Navigation Display, or ND.  You're correct that the PFD is something else, with the attitude indicator and airspeed & altitude tapes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Those are radials off of the HME navaid, which is tuned in both Nav receivers. The two radials displayed correspond to the courses set in the two course select windows.

Putting a navaid's identifier into the FMC "FIX" page can also generate similar bearing lines, although there would be a green circle around the navaid in that case.

An ILS (also the departure runway in the flightplan) extended centerline shows as white, not green, and appears when that ILS (or any other) approach is active in the route, rather than when the frequency is tuned.

Answer (score -1):

Thise dashed green lines appear to be extended center lines for each runway.  Most likely those are the runways with an ILS.

Comment: Close, but not correct.

Comment: They can't be extended centerlines for two runways because they are converging and you'd never build an airport with almost-parallel runways like that. Specifically, Haneda doesn't have any runways aligned close to the depicted directions.

Comment: @pericynthion Tegel airport in Berlin (EDDT) had runways that were not quite parallel... It does exist :)